# How to use the the same connection pool for many sources with DBResolver

Tags: go, multi-tenant, go-gorm

```
var databases = []string{"db_tenant1", "db_tenant2", "db_tenant3"}
connString := "postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable"
db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(connString), &gorm.Config{})
require.NoError(t, err)

dr := &dbresolver.DBResolver{}
for _, dbname := range databases {
    connString := fmt.Sprintf("postgres://%s:%s@localhost:5432/%s?sslmode=disable", "user", "password", dbname)
    dr = dr.Register(dbresolver.Config{
        Sources: []gorm.Dialector{postgres.Open(connString)},
        Policy:  dbresolver.RandomPolicy{},
    }, dbname, &TheObject{})
}
err = db.Use(dr.SetMaxOpenConns(1))
require.NoError(t, err)

for idx, dbname := range databases {
    result := db.Clauses(dbresolver.Use(dbname), dbresolver.Write).Create(TheObject{})
    require.NoError(t, result.Error)
}
require.NoError(t, err)
```

hi
i'm using GORM DBResolver to work with many sources (not replicas).
i see GORM creates connection for each database i'm using:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity
```

returns:

```
12379   postgres    3616
16496   db_tenant1  3617
16606   db_tenant2  3618
16716   db_tenant3  3619
```

i would like to have only one connection (from one pool) for all databases (schemas).

Comment: The database is specified per connection. So you can't really do what you're asking.  You could _kind of_ do what you want, by specifying the same database in the connection string in all cases, then using `USE <database>;` before each query. But you'd have to use transactions or similar, to ensure that the same connection is used for the entire query. But that's a lot of complexity for no real gain. Best advice; Just use the tool as intended.

Comment: If you ever have different permissions and/or credentials per database, then this strategy would fail completely, anyway.

Comment: thank you @JonathanHall, even _"kind of"_ does not work for postgres database since it has no `use <database>;`

Comment: Right, good call. So there's literally no way to do what you're requesting. :)